# Adding buttons to map infowindow android

Tags: android, google-maps

In the new Google Maps for Android API v2, I can very easily get custom markers and info windows to display. However, I'm trying to have multiple buttons inside of my info window, that each perform a different `onClick` action but the problem is, the map treats the InfoWindow as it's own button object (no matter where I click on the InfoWindow, it presses the entire thing). Does anyone know how to customize this a bit more?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just found this in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker).

> As mentioned in the previous section on info windows, an info window
>   is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the
>   map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded
>   and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of
>   the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such
>   as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info
>   window.

Unfortunately, that answers it. I was trying to add the same function as you.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was trying to convince my project manager that this is now the case, and couldn't find anywhere in the documentation that explicitly mentioned it. I should be able to show him this now and have the functionality reworked moving forward.

Comment: Here you will find it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: Related documentation moved to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows