# Custom infowindow in Google map android v2

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using Google Map API V2 and i have created a custom `InfoWindow` for a `Marker` on map.In this `InfoWindow` i have a button.

My problem is unable to set Onclicklistener/functioning to that Button(Dummy).Any one give me some idea to solve this :

[image]

Here is code snippet:

```
public class MarkerView extends FragmentActivity implements OnMarkerClickListener,OnInfoWindowClickListener{

private GoogleMap mMap;
private Marker chennai;
private View infoWindow;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_demo);

    infoWindow=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);

    mMap=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    chennai=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(13.0810, 80.274)).anchor(2, 1).title("Android").snippet("Snippet").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoAdapter());
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(null);
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    Button dummy=(Button) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.dummy);
    dummy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    dummy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MarkerView.this, "Dummy Button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}


class CustomInfoAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{


    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
        displayView(arg0);
        return infoWindow;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {

        return null;
    }


}


public void displayView(Marker arg0) {

    ((ImageView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
    ((ImageView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MarkerView.this, "Arrow Image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
     ((TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(arg0.getTitle());
     ((TextView)infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet)).setText(arg0.getTitle());

}


@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
    if(arg0.equals(chennai)){

        infoWindow.setClickable(false);

    }
    return false;
}


@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(MarkerView.this, "Info window", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Try it,

View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.your_custom_info_window_layout);



  Button bDummy = (Button) view
      .findViewById(R.id.button_dummy);
bDummy.setOnclick...
it may help you

Comment: Yes already tried.No use.

Comment: Could you post your code and I will look into it..

Comment: Take a look at my workaround here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps/15040761#15040761

Comment: did u get any result for this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2183804
It can help you!I tested it myself, and the method can be used.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please refer **Info window click events** in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

Info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.

Comment: Ah, do as I say, not as I do, huh Google? Google Maps has two touch targets on their application's InfoWindow. A search for something provides a segmented InfoWindow where you can touch the Nav icon to get directions or the text to get more info about the point of interest.

Comment: Sad, if only we could use the MapViewBalloons project for the old maps api.  https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

Comment: This explains why I can't click my AdMob banner placed within an InfoWindowAdapter

Answer (score 20):

You have to implement Custom marker; It is like this:

```
custommarker.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:background="#ADD8E6"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:src="@drawable/sabarmati" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity:

```
public class PlacesMapActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
    implements OnClickListener, LocationListener {
/**
 * Note that this may be null if the Google Play services APK is not
 * available.
 */
ImageButton btn_home;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    SupportMapFragment fragment =   (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mMap = fragment.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    // mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    // .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.title("First Location");
    markerOptions.snippet("This Is Test Location");

    LatLng latlng = new LatLng(23.0333, 72.6167);

    markerOptions.position(latlng);
    // markerOptions.title("Ahmedabad Cordinat Found here");

    // Marker m = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    ***mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            View myContentView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.custommarker, null);
            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView) myContentView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title));
            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());
            TextView tvSnippet = ((TextView) myContentView
                    .findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            tvSnippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());
            return myContentView;
        }
    });***

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latlng)
            .title("This is Sabarmati Ashram")
            .snippet("Ahmedabad")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),
                    DetailsOfPlacesActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    btn_home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.activity_map_ibtn_home);
    btn_home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: The secret was setOnInfoWindowClickListener . Perfect.

Comment: How does this get which part of the info window was clicked? I can't see how it would work.

Answer (score 0):

UI elements inside InfoWindow that appears on the markers of Google Maps are not clickable. So its better to use custom pop ups.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot click the button, because of [the reason explained by @TamiL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14477270/4170242).
However, you can click the `InfoWindow`, so, store the ID(s) of the `Marker`(s) whose `InfoWindow`(s) should be clickable, add a `GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener` to the map like this:

```
map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
    {
        // Called when ANY InfoWindow is clicked
    }
});
```

Then, when the `onInfoWindowClick` is called, compare the clicked `Marker`'s ID with the ones that you stored earlier, and if any of them match, execute whatever code should be executed in the `Button`'s click listener.

You don't have to deal with saving the `Marker` ID:s if all your `Marker`s' `InfoWindow`s are going to be clickable!

Answer (score 0):

I have build a sample android studio project for this question.

So you can create a Google map v2 Custom Infowindow with clickable buttons or ImageView, etc.,

**output screen shots :-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Download full project source code Click** **[here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ku97ajose03bpvt/AADGMLxT0n_kTp5rMK1b8SdSa?dl=0)**

**Please note:** you have to add your API key in Androidmanifest.xml

Comment: maybe upload it to github or some other repo.