# How to implement custom interactive balloon(infowindow) on maps api v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps, android-maps-v2

My question is simmilar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475059/custom-infowindow-in-google-map-android-v2).
The main difference is that i have to implement `InfoWindow` (also interactive) not only for markers but for any point on the map which user taps(in particular polygons and polylines).

Is there any suitable solution like `BalloonItemizedOverlay` for v1?

Answer (score 2):

When user clicks on a map and your `OnMapClickListener.onMapClick` is called, simply create a `Marker` with 0 by 0 pixels icon and force showing info window with `marker.showInfoWindow()`.

Comment: This is a solution to show `InfoWindow`. But how can i create `InfoWindow` user can interact with(i had to place few buttons with different actions and info there)? Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/1562477 chose007 describes his solution, but it looks too tricky) Another way is to implement infoWindow using `PopupWindow` but disadvantages of this approach also described in his answer.

Comment: @JohnnyDoe In your case there is no `Marker`, so you can simply show a nice `Dialog` with custom background and things. That would perfectly fit.

Comment: sorry, i probably poorly formulated question. I have markers, polygons and polylines. `BalloonItemizedOverlay`-like behavior is exactly what i want to achieve(i have used it with maps v1).