# Android: How to display Q&A Radio Button when user clicks a map marker

Tags: android, eclipse, popup, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm new to Android developing and I'm a GIS/Maps guy so to keep me interested I thought I'd focus on using Google Maps to create a kind of quiz.

I had an idea to have a Google Map display a bunch of Markers around an area and then when the user taps a Marker, a question will pop up (Radio Button?) with multiple answers and then the right answer will be displayed after the user clicks one of the options (toast?).

I've got a map to display markers and produce a popup when those points are pressed, but I don't know how to have a Radio Button popup and display the question and answers and then display the correct answer.

I've been at it for days and I'm nowhere.

**edit: changed title and text to use correct references, namely Radio Button instead of Popup and Marker instead of Point.**

**edit: image of what I have so far (map displaying multiple markers and popups when markers are pressed) available [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFQx8.jpg) (I can't post images yet!).**

Comment: check this link i think it's impossible to handle click events on infoview of marker http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475059/custom-infowindow-in-google-map-android-v2

Comment: @JigneshJain Thanks for the link. I've edited my post. I've got an AlertDialog to show up when I click a marker on the map, but I think I need it to be a Radio Button. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: yes you can easily do it i give you suggestion first show your question on info when user click on info window than open custom dialog with radiobutton