# Google Maps Android API v2 - InfoWindow with clickable buttons

Tags: maps, infowindow

I'm trying to put multiple buttons inside an GoogleMaps InfoWindos.

I know that: "Info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window."

Soo I'm looking for an alternative.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Take a look at my workaround here:  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps/15040761#15040761

Answer (score -2):

impliment the `infowindowcliclistner`.