# Google Maps API v2 for Android using FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY

Tags: java, android, google-maps, user-interface, google-maps-android-api-2

I was viewing a different question [Google Maps Android API v2 - Interactive InfoWindow (like in original android google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/) and as you can see he's using the requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY); to make the map v2 use the full screen. I tried this but the my location button is partially covered by the action bar on mine unlike his. Does anyone know how to move it down slightly?

Thanks!

[image: Mine looks like this]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't have any control over this button. Obviously, you can search for this button `id` in android sources and change layout params manually from the code, but I definitely wouldn't do that.

This button is super easy to implement yourself. So I recommend to disable built-in "locate me" button and implement your own which will be positioned right below the action bar.

To disable it use:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```

New button `onClick` method content:

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(googleMap.getMyLocation().getLatitude(),
                                                                 googleMap.getMyLocation().getLongitude())));
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had to do the following below. I was getting a location layer not enabled exception otherwise.
  
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the view by its id and re-set the top margin Apparently the id is always 2, but this isn't documented and your app will break when/if the id ever changes. Like Pavel said, it's safer to make your own location button and wire it up.

Unfortunately, calling ActionBar.getHeight() in your onCreate will always return 0 since layout hasn't finished. The way to get the real heigh is by using a listener on the ViewTreeObserver:

```
mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
     new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
          public void onGlobalLayout() {
               int actionBarHeight = getActionBar().getHeight();
               // TODO: set margin of views dependent on actionbar height
               // remove the listener
               mainLayout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
          }
     }
}
```