# Dynamic contents in Maps V2 InfoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow, universal-image-loader

I want to show an InfoWindow on markers in a Maps V2 fragment. 
Thing is, I want to show BitMaps that are dynamically loaded from the web with [Universal Image Downloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

This is my InfoWindowAdapter:

```
class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View v;

    MyInfoWindowAdapter() {
        v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_map,
                null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {



        Item i = items.get(marker.getId());

        TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        tv1.setText(i.getTitle());


        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .delayBeforeLoading(5000).build();

        imageLoader.getMemoryCache(); 

        imageLoader.displayImage(i.getThumbnailUrl(), iv, options,
                new ImageLoadingListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view,
                            FailReason failReason) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                            View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        Log.d("MAP", "Image loaded " + imageUri);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri,
                            View view) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
    });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have 2 problems with this:

As we [know](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_window_click_events) the `InfoWindow` is drawn and later changes to it (in my case the new `BitMap` on the `ImageView`) are not shown/ the `InfoWindow` is not being updated. How can I "notify" the InfoWindow to reload itself when the `imageLoader` has finished? When I put

```
marker.showInfoWindow()
```

into `onLoadingComplete` it created an infinite loop where the marker will pop up, start loading the image, pop itself up etc.

My second problem is that on a slow network connection (simulated with the 5000ms delay in the code), the `ImageView` in the `InfoWindow` will always display the last loaded image, no matter if that image belongs to that `ImageWindow`/ `Marker`.

Any suggestions on how to propperly implement this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should be doing `Marker.showInfoWindow()` on marker that is currently showing info window when you receive model update.

So you need to do 3 things:

1. create model and not put all the downloading into `InfoWindowAdapter`
2. save reference to Marker (call it `markerShowingInfoWindow`)
   from `getInfoContents(Marker marker)`
3. when model notifies you of download complete call

```
if (markerShowingInfoWindow != null && markerShowingInfoWindow.isInfoWindowShown()) {
    markerShowingInfoWindow.showInfoWindow();
}
```

Comment: Can anyone please put the code if anyone have solved the issue?

Comment: Programming is not about doing a copy-paste operation. My answer should be easy to follow and if it is not, you may ask a question to clarify things.

Comment: If the user clicks another marker before onLoadingComplete, won't the wrong infoWindow receive that download?

Comment: @Ejmedina info window doesn't receive downloads. In my architecture proposition model stores image, notifies view controller (activity / fragment), which checks if currently shown info window should be updated: when downloaded image is associated with model object for which info window is displayed.

Comment: Thank @MaciejGórski for your clarification. I'll try to follow your proposition. How should the model notify the view? Have you implemented this?

Comment: In the simplest form you can use Observer pattern. You can also use broadcasts (see [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)) or event bus (e.g. [Otto from Square](https://github.com/square/otto)). Yes, I did.

Comment: @MaciejGórski thanks, it works! I used EventBus (from greenrobot).

Comment: @MaciejGórski hey thanks.. i think the method got changed..markerShowingInfoWindow.isInfoWindowShown().. works for me..

Comment: @sham.y Nice catch after almost 2 years. I was probably typing this from my head and without looking at the documentation. The method name could not change. I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: If I only do as the answer, the infinite loop problem is  still there ! I have to add a cache of type HashMap<Marker,Bitmap>, so everytime I need to load image, I will check whether the image already loaded, that how I solve the infinite calling getInfoContents() problem. Or did I misunderstand something ?

Answer (score 5):

I did something similar. 
This was still giving me the recession error

```
if (markerShowingInfoWindow != null && markerShowingInfoWindow.isShowingInfoWindow()) {
    markerShowingInfoWindow.showInfoWindow();
}
```

So what i did was simply closes the window and open it again

```
if (markerShowingInfoWindow != null && markerShowingInfoWindow.isShowingInfoWindow()) {

    markerShowingInfoWindow.hideInfoWindow();
    markerShowingInfoWindow.showInfoWindow();

}
```

for a better detail version of the same answer here is my original soultion [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22690182/1356819)

Comment: This looks more like a comment to the accepted answer. If you really need to do this, then it seems to be a bug in Google Maps Android API v2. I have never encountered this bug tho and had no problems without using hide...

Comment: Simply calling .showInfoWindow again worked for me! Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced same situation and solved using the following code.

In my adapter I have added public variable

```
public class MarkerInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    public String ShopName="";   

    -------
    -------

     @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {

         View v;
         v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);

         TextView shop= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_shop);

         shop.setText(ShopName);


    }
}
```

and added MarkerClickListener in my main activity

```
----

MarkerInfoWindowAdapter mMarkerInfoWindowAdapter;

----
----

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    mMarkerInfoWindowAdapter = new MarkerInfoWindowAdapter(getApplicationContext());



    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker arg0) {

            mMarkerInfoWindowAdapter.ShopName= "my dynamic text";

            arg0.showInfoWindow();

            return true;
        }
    }

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mMarkerInfoWindowAdapter);


}
```