# Android GoogleMap 2 update information dynamically in InfoWindow with ImageView via Universal Image loader

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, universal-image-loader

I am working on new Google Map v2 API.

I have used ImageLoader to display images dynamically on Marker.

But the problem is when I have got onLoadingComplete() of Universal Image Loader, the ImageView is not invalidated neither automatically nor manually.

Next time if I click on the same Marker, image will be displayed from Cache of Universal Image Loader.

Below is my **CustomInfoWindowAdapter** code :

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        final View mWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);

        render(marker, mWindow);
        return mWindow;
    }

    private void render(final Marker marker, View view) {

        final String url = markers.get(marker.getId()).getStrProfilePic();
        final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));
        Log.e(TAG, "URL : " + url);

        if ( url != null && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                        Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                    ((ImageView) view).invalidate();
                }
            });
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
        }

        final String title = marker.getTitle();
        final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        if (title != null) {
            titleUi.setText(title);
        } else {
            titleUi.setText("");
        }

        final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        if (snippet != null) {
            snippetUi.setText(snippet);
        } else {
            snippetUi.setText("");
        }
    }
}
```

I stores Marker Ids in HashTable when I add Marker. And from their I will get the URL of photo.

Comment: Display options? Configuration? Do you call `displayImage(...)` on UI thread?

Comment: In render(final Marker marker, View view), I have called imageLoader.displayImage(....) method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have taken one Marker object at class level and used that object to update the Marker information.

I have Customized my class as below to update the ImageView :

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private View view;

    public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);          
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

        if ( YourClassName.this.marker != null &&
                ClassName.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown() ) {
            YourClassName.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
            YourClassName.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
        YourClassName.this.marker = marker;

        final String url = markers.get(marker.getId()).getStrProfilePic();
        final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));

        if ( url != null && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                        Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                    getInfoContents(marker);
                }
            });
        } else {
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
        }

        final String title = marker.getTitle();
        final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
        if (title != null) {
            titleUi.setText(title);
        } else {
            titleUi.setText("");
        }

        final String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
        final TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
        if (snippet != null) {
            snippetUi.setText(snippet);
        } else {
            snippetUi.setText("");
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

[Check the Example](http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2013/08/display-custom-info-window-with.html)

Comment: In my application, I do not ave to show multiple maps. But In Map2, it is possible to display multiple maps. Demo is available in android sdk with google play service.

Comment: @NishantShah +1 for your answer but.  if you post your blog url in comment than it will easier for whole example :) http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/  thanks :)

Comment: Genius! the only method of refreshing the info window that actually worked for me :D

Answer (score 3):

View returned from info window callbacks cannot be updated afterwards.

Try following this suggestion: [Dynamic contents in Maps V2 InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503266/dynamic-contents-in-maps-v2-infowindow/15512984#15512984)