# Image not loading in google map marker using UiL

Tags: android, google-maps, universal-image-loader

I am using `universal-image-loader-1.9.5.jar`. I am trying to display user image on marker. But image is not being displayed.

**What have i done .**

**UIL initialization**

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.profile_image) // resource or drawable
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.profile_image) // resource or drawable
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.profile_image) // resource or drawable
        .resetViewBeforeLoading(false)  // default
        .delayBeforeLoading(1000)
        .cacheInMemory(false) // default
        .cacheOnDisk(false) // default
        .considerExifParams(false) // default
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2) // default
        .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) // default
        .displayer(new SimpleBitmapDisplayer()) // default
        .handler(new Handler()) // default
        .build();


File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(this);
config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
.memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
.diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, null)
.threadPoolSize(3) // default
.threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2) // default
.tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
.memoryCache(new LruMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024))
.memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
.memoryCacheSizePercentage(13) // default
.diskCache(new UnlimitedDiskCache(cacheDir)) // default
.diskCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
.diskCacheFileCount(100)
.diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
.defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
.writeDebugLogs()
.build();
imageLoader.init(config);
```

**Using InfoWindowAdapter**

```
googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyCustomAdapterForItems());

public class MyCustomAdapterForItems implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    private final View myContentsView;

    MyCustomAdapterForItems() {
        myContentsView = mainFragmentActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.map_info_window_dialog, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonMarker = new JSONObject(marker.getSnippet());
            String name = jsonMarker.getString("name");
            double distance = jsonMarker.getDouble("distance");
            String imagePath = jsonMarker.getString("profile_pic_address");
            String gender = jsonMarker.getString("gender");
            String birthDate = jsonMarker.getString("birthdate");
            age = hiApplication.getAge(birthDate);
            TextView tvName = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvMapChatName));
            TextView tvAge = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvMapChatAge));
            TextView tvDistance = ((TextView) myContentsView
                    .findViewById(R.id.distance));
            TextView tvGender = (TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.tvChatGender);
            RoundedImageView  image = (RoundedImageView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            imageLoader.displayImage(imagePath, image , defaultOptions , simpleLoader); //Image loading here
            tvName.setText(name);
            if(age == 0 ) tvAge.setText("");
            else tvAge.setText(age+"");
            tvGender.setText(gender);
            tvDistance.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(distance)+ " km.");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return myContentsView;
    }
}
```

**ImageLoadingListener**

```
private class SimpleLoader implements ImageLoadingListener {

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {
            Log.d("d", "image cancelled");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
            Log.d("d", "loading complete");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1, FailReason arg2) {
            Log.d("d", "image loading failed");

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {
            Log.d("d", "image loading started");
        }

    }
```

Although my logs show that image is loaded completely . Here is my logs .

```
01-21 02:38:13.561: D/d(7832): image loading started
01-21 02:38:13.567: D/ImageLoader(7832): Delay 1000 ms before loading...  [http://192.168.1.9:8080/chatme_userimages/ttestttt@gmail.com.jpg_100x100]
01-21 02:38:14.568: D/ImageLoader(7832): Start display image task [http://192.168.1.9:8080/chatme_userimages/ttestttt@gmail.com.jpg_100x100]
01-21 02:38:14.569: D/ImageLoader(7832): Load image from network [http://192.168.1.9:8080/chatme_userimages/ttestttt@gmail.com.jpg_100x100]
01-21 02:38:14.653: D/ImageLoader(7832): Display image in ImageAware (loaded from NETWORK) [http://192.168.1.9:8080/chatme_userimages/ttestttt@gmail.com.jpg_100x100]
01-21 02:38:14.653: D/d(7832): loading complete
```

But only default drawb `R.drawable.profile_image` is showing all the time. 
Can anybody tell me , am i missing something here ? Whats wrong with code ?

Comment: check the url of image if it's correct or not

Comment: @VivekMishra . Image path  `http://192.168.1.9:8080/chatme_userimages/ttestttt@gmail.com.jpg` is correct it is shown on my browsser , but i dont know why Imageloader adds suffix  `_100x100`  to my image path . which makes it wrong path .

Comment: I think that may be due to default_options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution of my problem , following some suggestions from [Dynamic contents in Maps V2 InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503266/dynamic-contents-in-maps-v2-infowindow)

and [Android GoogleMap 2 update information dynamically in InfoWindow with ImageView via Universal Image loader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16144341/android-googlemap-2-update-information-dynamically-in-infowindow-with-imageview)

The problem with above code is `getInfoWindow(Marker marker)` is being called before downloading the image hence it was not showing updated UI.

So i am updating infowindow() using `marker.showInfoWindow()` and `marker.hideInfoWindow()` after image downloaded .

I have done following changes in my code .

```
@Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            if ( FragmentMap.this.marker != null && FragmentMap.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {

                FragmentMap.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
                FragmentMap.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
                FragmentMap.this.marker  = null ;
            }
            return null;
        }



@Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            try {
                Log.d("d", "inside getinfowindow");
                FragmentMap.this.marker = marker;
                JSONObject jsonMarker = new JSONObject(marker.getSnippet());
                String name = jsonMarker.getString("name");
                double distance = jsonMarker.getDouble("distance");
                String imagePath = jsonMarker.getString("profile_pic_address");
                String gender = jsonMarker.getString("gender");
                String birthDate = jsonMarker.getString("birthdate");
                age = hiApplication.getAge(birthDate);
                TextView tvName = ((TextView) myContentsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvMapChatName));
                TextView tvAge = ((TextView) myContentsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvMapChatAge));
                TextView tvDistance = ((TextView) myContentsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.distance));
                TextView tvGender = (TextView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.tvChatGender);
                RoundedImageView  image = (RoundedImageView) myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
                imageLoader.displayImage(imagePath, image , defaultOptions , simpleLoader);
                tvName.setText(name);
                if(age == 0 ) tvAge.setText("");
                else tvAge.setText(age+"");
                tvGender.setText(gender);
                tvDistance.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(distance)+ " km.");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return myContentsView;
        }
```

**Inside class SimpleLoader**

```
@Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, final View view,  Bitmap bitmap) {

            markerCustomAdapter.getInfoContents(marker);
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Above code is working fine on android 4.0.4 , but when i tried this code on android lolipop, images were not getting loaded. So i followed  [Add an Image from url into custom InfoWindow google maps v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18938187/add-an-image-from-url-into-custom-infowindow-google-maps-v2?answertab=active#tab-top)   and used http://square.github.io/picasso/  Picasso library . Now its working fine for me.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

*You should create a custom xml layout file and then inflate in method getInfoContents(Marker arg0)

Your image is prepared but it is not getting loaded on the marker I think.

Try this

```
 @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

            // Getting the position from the marker
            LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

            // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
            TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

            // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
            TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

            // Setting the latitude
            tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);

            // Setting the longitude
            tvLng.setText("Longitude:"+ latLng.longitude);

            // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
            return v;

        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried inflating my xml in  `getInfoContents(Marker arg0)` but now it does not show my markers even.

Comment: Try getting image from imageloader then set it do not try to directly display it.

Comment: This code works for me there might be an error in your code

Comment: In my app images are being downloaded from web server dymamically . I tried your code but it did not work for me . I have solved this issue. Please have a look  at my answer .