# Android add dynamics data to InfoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, infowindow

I am working on an application using a Google Map and the Google Places API, let's say I populate the map with different Markers and that I keep track of those Markers inside a

```
Map<Marker, Place> places = new HashMap<Marker, Place>();
```

Here is my Place's class :

```
    public class Place {
    String placeId;
    String name;

    public Place(String placeId, String name) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to dynamically fill an InfoWindow with data fetched based on the placeId argument, here is what I do inside the InfoWindowAdapter :

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window_layout, null);
                TextView placeName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_place_name);
                Place place = places.get(marker);
                if (place != null) {
                    placeName.setText(place.name);
                    String photoUrl = "http://www.plopcontenido.com/wp/wp-content/themes/PlopTheme/img/logo.png";
                    new DownloadPlacePhoto(v, marker, placeName.toString()).execute(photoUrl);
                }
                return v;
            }
        });

    private class DownloadPlacePhoto extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    View v;
    Marker marker;
    String placeName;

    public DownloadPlacePhoto(View v, Marker marker, String placeName) {
        this.v = v;
        this.marker = marker;
        this.placeName = placeName;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap download;
        try {
            InputStream in = new URL(urls[0]).openStream();
            download = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return download;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap download) {
        if (download != null) {
            ImageView placeImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_place_photo);
            placeImage.setImageBitmap(download);
            placeImage.setContentDescription(this.placeName);
            placeImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
                this.marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is the InfoWindow is a "snapshot" and not a live representation (and I totally understand why) is that the associated Asynctask will run inside another thread so the snapshot will already be taken without my fetched data.

I heard people talking about Observer Pattern and other talking about "you need to get your data stored before you enter the getInfoWindow function, but due to Google Places limitations I can't afford to perform two more requests (one for the picture, and the other one for more data about a specific place) for each Marker.

Any idea about how I could perform this ?

Comment: This may be helpful, it's about adding an image to the InfoWindow after creating it, but it's basically the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503266/dynamic-contents-in-maps-v2-infowindow

Comment: I already seen this post, but I am not really an Android guru, still trying to learn things and the author is a little bit too broad for me.

Answer (score 0):

The gist of [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503266/dynamic-contents-in-maps-v2-infowindow) is to re-show the `InfoWindow` with `marker.showInfoWindow()` when you have all the data you need and until then you could show the data you already have or some "loading ..."-text. 
When doing so, you have to check if the user unselected the respective marker or selected another marker in the meantime.

Comment: I tried to do this (and will update my code to show it) but I just get the InfoWindow refreshed every 3 or 4 seconds (without the picture showed)