# how to make the content in the marker info window clickable in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am using a custom layout to be displayed as Infowindow when clicked on map marker in android.

[image]

In the above picture, when I clcik on EditText to enter the name, I did observe that Edit Text is not being edited and the Whole window is getting selected. How to make the fields clickable in an infowindow when custom layout is used?

Please suggest me any Idea. Please Help!!

Comment: This is old, but check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go) thread out.

Comment: Did you get the same result? I also want to type message In Info window with edit text

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The quick answer: `you can't.`

Google Map renders the content of you custom `InfoWindow` into an image and displays it to you as an Image. Therefore you set a click Listener only to the whole window and not to the Views inside it.

Your only choice it to set the `ClickListener` to the whole `InfoWindow` and popup an Dialog with the `EditText` View you want, and not do it directly inside the `InfoWindow`.

From `Google Docs`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`.
>   Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

Comment: Thanks Emil!! Any way I need to follow what you told.

Comment: what do you mena by: "Any way I need to follow that"?

Comment: I mean I do not have other choice and need to follow ur suggestion.

Comment: you can see the updated answer to get this source of this info.