# How to add image into InfoWindow of marker in google maps API V2 Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

i have this

```
 mapa.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                       .position(latlng)
                       .title("HI")
                       .snippet("HI;HI")
           .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.same)));
```

but no find information of how add into infowindow a icon 
someone can help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to [create your own `InfoWindowAdapter`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows) and use `getInfoContents()` or `getInfoWindow()` to return the info window contents containing the image you seek.

Comment: It's not great documentation is it? There are no concrete examples of the InfoWindowAdapter interface, just pictures of what it should look like if you manage to guess correctly.