# Button on android map annotation

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

After a while of googling I cannot find what I need, I see some libraries which look to do it but I have already implemented the system using androids default methods.

I set the markers like so:

```
theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
                .title(title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin_map32))
                .snippet(strap));
```

However I need a 'detail disclosure button' like on iOS (transitioning app from iOS to Android) and I can't seem to add a button to the marker - is it possible using androids system?

Comment: you mean like clicking on a marker on the map?

Comment: @tyczj Not quite, so you click a marker and an annotation pops up just fine - I need to add a button to the right hand side of the annotation which will open up the web browser and load a new activity.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done.

from the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker)

`Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow(). Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.`

in other words you cannot put a button in the infowindow and be able to use it. You will need to use a dialog of sorts if you want to do something like that

Comment: Bahhh really? How frustrating. I dont suppose there are any work arounds to adding a button to the view?

Comment: currently no, you need to use a dialog like i said or else just use the whole view as a button like it says in the docs and show what you want

Comment: Ahh okay, that could do. Is it possible to set a "hidden" field on each pin, like there is title, snippet etc - is it possible to have a `url` property and then when you detect the click do `theMap.getURL()` and have the custom property go in logcat?

Comment: No, you are pretty limited with what you can do with markers and infowindows. I would suggest creating some sort of class that holds all marker data and create a `hashmap` with a `key` of the `markerID` then the data is the class so you can pull any information from the hashmap based on the marker id

Comment: @JoshBoothe `Is it possible to set a "hidden" field on each pin`. For that I would suggest [Android Maps Extensions](https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/) which adds `Marker.setData` and `Marker.getData` methods.

Answer (score 1):

There is always some way.

A nice hack can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2183804

I haven't tested it myself, but from the comments there (and the amount of upvotes) we can deduce it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can track clicks only on Marker. If you want a button on marker - click on marker & show a dialog with buttons.