# Change background color at onTouch event on InfoWindow Google Map Api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, background, infowindow

I have created their own InfoWindow in my Google Map activity. I set background color, but at change event onClick or onTouch, the background color is changed on blue. How to changed own color on background color?

Comment: set selector as background of your infowindow layout file

Comment: this is my selector: 
`<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="0dip" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90"  android:startColor="#ffd79e00" android:endColor="#ffd79e00" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>`

Answer (score 0):

This is waiting in the feature requests queue on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4783), so not easily possible to make it work yourself.

You can however try this nice hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2183804
It is used there to make clickable buttons on info window, but can also be used for your case.