# Google Maps api V2 InfoWindowAdapter has textview & Imageview event!, how to handle two event?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi i working on demo application for google map with custom pop-up.
please suggest me how to handle textview & image view click handle.
i can't get event. below are my code.

```
class PopupAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater=null;
        Context context;
        PopupAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater, Context context) {
            this.inflater=inflater;
            this.context = context;
        }

        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            return(null);
        }

        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            MyModel mapItem = (MyModel) MainActivity.markers.get(marker.getId());  
            View popup=inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);

            TextView tv=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageView im = (ImageView)popup.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            tv.setText(marker.getTitle());
            tv=(TextView)popup.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
            tv.setText(marker.getSnippet());


            im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.e("POPUP", "Image Click");
        }
        });

            tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

        Log.e("POPUP", "HI");
        Toast.makeText(context, "HI", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    });

    return(popup);
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AbstractMapActivity implements
OnNavigationListener, OnInfoWindowClickListener {
private static final String STATE_NAV="nav";
private static final int[] MAP_TYPE_NAMES= { R.string.normal,
    R.string.hybrid, R.string.satellite, R.string.terrain };
  private static final int[] MAP_TYPES= { GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL,
      GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID, GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE,
      GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN };
  private GoogleMap map=null;
  public static HashMap<String, MyModel> markers= new HashMap<String, MyModel>();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (readyToGo()) {
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      SupportMapFragment mapFrag=
          (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

      initListNav();

      map=mapFrag.getMap();

      if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        CameraUpdate center=
            CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(40.76793169992044,
                                                     -73.98180484771729));
        CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

        map.moveCamera(center);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);
      }
        MyModel item = new MyModel();
        item.setId("1");
        item.setName("Bhavesh");
        item.setAdd("Krishnanagar");  
      addMarker(map, 40.748963847316034, -73.96807193756104,R.string.un, R.string.united_nations,item);
      item = new MyModel();
        item.setId("2");
        item.setName("Kunal");
        item.setAdd("Bhavnagar");  
      addMarker(map, 40.76866299974387, -73.98268461227417,R.string.lincoln_center,R.string.lincoln_center_snippet,item);
      item = new MyModel();
        item.setId("3");
        item.setName("Ravi");
        item.setAdd("Ahmedabad");  
      addMarker(map, 40.765136435316755, -73.97989511489868,R.string.carnegie_hall, R.string.practice_x3,item);
      item = new MyModel();
        item.setId("3");
        item.setName("Binitbhai");
        item.setAdd("Shivranjani");  
      addMarker(map, 40.70686417491799, -74.01572942733765,R.string.downtown_club, R.string.heisman_trophy,item);

      map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater(),MainActivity.this));
      map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    map.setMapType(MAP_TYPES[itemPosition]);

    return(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_NAV, getSupportActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
  }

  @Override
  public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_NAV));
  }

  @Override
  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {




//    MyModel mapItem = (MyModel) markers.get(marker.getId()); 

//    Toast.makeText(this,marker.getSnippet()+ marker.getTitle() + " "+mapItem.getName() +" "+mapItem.getAdd() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

  private void initListNav() {
    ArrayList<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> nav=null;
    ActionBar bar=getSupportActionBar();

    for (int type : MAP_TYPE_NAMES) {
      items.add(getString(type));
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
      nav=
          new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                   bar.getThemedContext(),
                                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                   items);
    }
    else {
      nav=
          new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                   this,
                                   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                   items);
    }

    nav.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    bar.setListNavigationCallbacks(nav, this);
  }

  private void addMarker(GoogleMap map, double lat, double lon, int title, int snippet,MyModel item) {
    markers.put(map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(getString(title)).snippet(getString(snippet)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE))).getId(), item);
//    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(getString(title)).snippet(getString(snippet)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));


  }
}
```

Please suggest me how to do this event.
thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in other answers what you want to achieve is not supported directly by Google Maps Android API v2, but...

you can do what you need by putting yourself in front of `MapFragment` or `MapView`, handle `MotionEvents` to make your `OnClickListener`s be called.

See this answer for a nice (but hackish) how-to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2183804

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put `OnClickListeners` on the contents of an info window. The info window itself is not displaying your layout, but rather a `Bitmap` generated from the layout. This is covered in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#info_window_events):

> As mentioned in the previous section on info windows, an info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.

You can [use `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setOnInfoWindowClickListener%28com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener%29) to find out when the info window itself is tapped.

Comment: onInfoWindowClick get marker click. but i want particular image and textview click than how to do?

Comment: @BhaveshVadalia: What you want is not supported.

Comment: okay... thank you so much

than i can't get textview and image click event.

Answer (score 0):

yes you cannot add listener on the view of info window. One thing you can do , onInfoWindowClick show alert menu and give the user some options.

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
            final CharSequence[] items = { "message", "call"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Call");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (item == 0) {
                sendMessage();
            } else {
                makeCall();

            }

        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
        }
    });
```

Or you can try something like this..
I am not sure whether its work or not.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/1792228

Comment: this is other way to use.