# Multiple targets in GoogleMap Marker InfoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to bundle multiple markers in my googlemap such that one marker shows and InfoWindow with multiple clickable regions like so:

```
/----------------\
|       1        |
|                |
------------------
|       2        |
|                |
------------------
|       3        |
|                |
\-------  -------/
        \/
```

Now I know that I cannot use a button because essentially a InfoWindow is an image but it is possible since you can register to OnInfoWindowClickListener and the background of the InfoWindow changes color when you click it.

If someone could even point me to the part of the sources responsible for making an InfoWindow respond to a click and triggering the OnInfoWindowClickListener interface I'd be very grateful. I am willing to share any working stub for other people to use as well.

Answer (score 0):

maps is not open source. I assume its the same as any button where the background changes color when the state button is clicked.

you can take a look at this but it its very hacky

[Google Maps Android API v2 - Interactive InfoWindow (like in original android google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps/15040761#15040761)

Comment: Ah that's why I couldn't find any sources. Is there any way I could insert myself in between the touch event and the re-rendering of the InfoWindow image you can think of?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I found that one too. The solution I am looking for needs to be production code worthy though and stable over API 8-X. Maybe I'll just use a DialogFragment to be shown after you click on the multi-result InfoWindow. That actually looks kinda nice. Thanks for thinking with me anyway!