# Android google maps, how to add a link in Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, hyperlink, google-maps-markers

Like many web google map. I want to have a link in the maker. Right now I can use googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() ....  to have html string, which I can change text font and size, but after I click the link in the mark, nothing happen. Should I block the default setOnMarkerClickListener?
Thanks.
I can not upload image. please refer this link's map
http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/store-locator.html

Comment: This can be done, but is not easy. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2183804

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, what you want is not possible. While you can detect a click on the whole info window, the widgets you put in the info window will not respond to touch events. That is because what is actually shown is a bitmap of what the widgets look like, not the widgets themselves.

Comment: ok... so functions on android have more limit than web. right?

Comment: @Jack: Well, in this area, perhaps. I cannot make that claim in general.