# Adding a HTML Content in a infoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

Hi Guys I am using Google Maps Android API v2. I loaded the Map and placed few Marker. I wanted to display a HTML URL in the "infoWindow" but Google seems to suggest its not possible https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows. can it be done using "OnInfoWindowClickListener"? So that i open a dialogue box using this listener which contains a HTML URL?

Comment: It is not possible to do that via html, but if you put view with `OnClickListener`, you can achieve that using method from an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps

Comment: I have already started working on trying OnInfoWindowClickListener solution below, if i am not able to achieve what i want will try your solution. THanks for trying to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wanted to display a HTML URL in the "infoWindow" but Google seems to suggest its not possible

You can *display* pretty much whatever you want in an info window (though I have not tried anything that uses a `SurfaceView`). You cannot respond to *clicks* on anything other than then entire info window.

> can it be done using "OnInfoWindowClickListener"? So that i open a dialogue box using this listener which contains a HTML URL?

You are welcome to do whatever you wish when the user clicks on an info window.

Comment: That was my problem, i.e. not being able to click the URL inside infoWindow. Could you help me with some sample codes on onInfoWindowClicklistener ?

Comment: @rajatbhivania: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Popups is a sample app that has an `OnInfoWindowClickListener`. In my case, I just display a `Toast`, but you could `show()` a `DialogFragment`, or `startActivity()`, or execute a `FragmentTransaction`, or pretty much whatever you want.