# Button onclicklistener on infowindow in google map

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

How can i detect the button setOnClickListener in info window on google map? 
Actually in my info window i have a button and i want to click on that button. Is this possible to do this?

Comment: Check out this answer, this can be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2136046

Comment: Thanx for your quick reply. actually the thing is i also using marker clustering in map and for clustering i am using a library so now it is really hard to assemble the code on clustering library classes.

Comment: did u get any result?

Answer (score 24):

Try it

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: this 'mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener' works click any part of the InfoWindow.

i need to write button click event inside the InfoWindow. is it possible ?

Comment: @PremkumarManipillai no.  InfoWindows are rendered as images and are not live views.

Answer (score 7):

Actually it not posiable, Google Map renders the content of you custom `InfoWindow` into an image and displays it to you as an Image. Therefore you set a click Listener only to the whole window and not to the Views inside it.

Your only choice it to set the `ClickListener` to the whole `InfoWindow` and popup an Dialog with clickable content you want, and not do it directly inside the `InfoWindow`.

From `Google Docs`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`.
>   Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

Comment: The Above answer is correct see this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#info_windows

Comment: This is a proper answer.Exactly what i was looking for. didn't solve my problem but still you told truth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this create own class as

```
    public abstract class OnInfoWindowItemTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    private final View view;
    private final int bgDrawableNormal;
    private final int bgDrawablePressed;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Marker marker;
    private boolean pressed = false;

    public OnInfoWindowItemTouchListener(View view, int bgDrawableNormal, int bgDrawablePressed) {
        this.view = view;
        this.bgDrawableNormal = bgDrawableNormal;
        this.bgDrawablePressed = bgDrawablePressed;
    }

    public void setMarker(Marker marker) {
        this.marker = marker;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View vv, MotionEvent event) { 
        if (0 <= event.getX() && event.getX() <= view.getWidth() &&
            0 <= event.getY() && event.getY() <= view.getHeight())
        {
            switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: startPress(); break;

            // We need to delay releasing of the view a little so it shows the pressed state on the screen
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: handler.postDelayed(confirmClickRunnable, 150); break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: endPress(); break;
            default: break;
            }
        }
        else {
            // If the touch goes outside of the view's area
            // (like when moving finger out of the pressed button)
            // just release the press
            endPress();
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void startPress() {
        if (!pressed) {
            pressed = true;
            handler.removeCallbacks(confirmClickRunnable);
            view.setBackgroundResource(bgDrawablePressed);
            if (marker != null) 
                marker.showInfoWindow();
        }
    }

    private boolean endPress() {
        if (pressed) {
            this.pressed = false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(confirmClickRunnable);
            view.setBackgroundResource(bgDrawableNormal);
            if (marker != null) 
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    private final Runnable confirmClickRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (endPress()) {
                onClickConfirmed(view, marker);
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * This is called after a successful click 
     */
    protected abstract void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker);
}
```

Use it in your activity:

```
    final OnInfoWindowItemTouchListener buttonListener = new         OnInfoWindowItemTouchListener(markHere, 0, 0) {
                @Override
                protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
//  more code goes here
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks shylendra for your quick reply. But i just want to know how you find the click event over info window?

Answer (score 0):

We actually tried to address this issue by developing a library the can ease the creation of live(interactive) info windows.

https://github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid

I know it is an old question but I hope it can help someone in the future.

You can basically add your own fragment as an info window using the manager provided by our library. The following is a snipped of how easily the library can be used. Check the link above for more information

```
 final MapInfoWindowFragment mapInfoWindowFragment =
    (MapInfoWindowFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.infoWindowMap);
 final InfoWindow infoWindow = new InfoWindow(marker, markerSpec, fragment);
// Shows the InfoWindow or hides it if it is already opened.
 mapInfoWindowFragment.infoWindowManager().toggle(infoWindow, true);
```