# Image Button is not working in InfoWindowAdapter in google map v2

Tags: android, android-mapview, imagebutton, android-maps-v2

I am trying to add some image button in my marker info.
Though the buttons are added in the view but i cat not click on them.
When I try to click it clicks on the whole view.
My code us given below.

MainActivity.java

```
private GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final RelativeLayout base;
    base = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.base);
    googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMap();
    try {           
        initilizeMap();   // Loading map
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("asdfadfadf", "asdfasdf");
    }       
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    //googleMap.clear();
    IconGenerator i = new IconGenerator(getBaseContext());
    i.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_BLUE);
    Bitmap tt = i.makeIcon("asdf");
    LatLng myLocation = new LatLng(22.899171, 89.500186);
    Marker myLocMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(myLocation)
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(tt))
    .title("sssss"));
    googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker mk) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ImageButton set,from,favor;
            View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_info,null);
            set = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonDestination);
            from = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFrom);
            favor = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFavourite);
            set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d("sssssssssssssssss", "sssssssssssssssss");
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
    });
}

/**
 * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
 * */
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();  // check if map is created successfully or not
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}

}
```

don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: read the note under custominfowindows https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows

Comment: I did.
cant understand what to do.

Comment: its clear. Quoting from the link  **the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events**. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the docs.

Comment: Here you can find a description on how to achieve your goal: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2183804

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add click listeners to the Marker's `InfoWindow` as it's not a real view. But a Bitmap that gets rendered from you layout.

From `Google Docs`: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#info_windows

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`.
>   Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

Answer (score 2):

Set GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() to your map, implement the interface. You get the marker passed to you, call you action form there:

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        //do your thing here
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well what you require, but according understanding is something of a click on an image to add to the map (a marker). if so may try this:

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            //Your code when you do click

            return false;
        }
    });
```

I hope help you, and Sorry for my english :(