# Info window with a button next to it? Google Maps API

Tags: android, xml, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm using Google Maps API v2 in my app and I made custom info window when marker is clicked.

**[This](http://shrani.si/f/1Z/UH/4JtLxS49/info1.png)** is how it looks like right now, nothing special, just a simple info window.

But now I want to do **[this](http://shrani.si/f/2G/Gx/4hcHCNEI/info2.png)**. So I want to put a button next to info window and the user needs to click the button that's next to the info window, not the info window itself.

Is this even possible? I did a lot of research on google and I didn't find a single thing that would help me. Is this even possible to achieve using this API? If it is, I would appreciate some pointers, useful links or even examples.

Comment: possible yes but I dont think in the sense you intend it to work, you can overlay something on the map in a view but if the map moves then your button wont follow the InfoWindow because its not relly on the map. Thats not to say you cant move the button on the view but it seems to be more work than what it worth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve clickability of a portion of an info window using a [nice hack posted on another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2183804). Just use a 9-patch with some transparent pixels here and there as a background.

You will have only a problem with placement of upside-down caret on info window. Until [this feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5842) is implemented, you can have it only at the bottom center.