# Change the color of info window clicked state?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I made a custom info window for my app that uses Google Maps API. When I click on the info window, the window is highlighted with holo blue.

I found this:

> When a user clicks on an info window, onInfoWindowClick(Marker) will be called and the info window will be highlighted in the default highlight color (Holo Blue for devices running Ice Cream Sandwich and newer, orange for earlier versions of Android).

So it says that it is holo blue by default, but I didn't find any information on how to change this. Can I change the color somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot as of 4.0.30 version of the library. Follow [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4783) to be notified when this is added in the API.

There is a way you could try to hack it. Follow this answer: [Google Maps Android API v2 - Interactive InfoWindow (like in original android google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps) and think of info window as a big button, where you handle clicks in `OnClickListener` instead of using `InfoWindowClickListener`.