# How to handle GoogleMap setOnInfoWindowClickListener with multiple click

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

[image]

- want to handle 2 Button click Individually for 2 different Intent like

  googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

  ```
              @Override
              public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                  Toast.makeText(mcontext, "v-"+marker.getId(), 212).show();

                   btnopen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                         
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {                               
                              Toast.makeText(mcontext, "btnopen-Clicked", 212).show();
                          }
                      });

                      btnshedule.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                           
                          @Override
                          public void onClick(View v) {
                              Toast.makeText(mcontext, "btnShedule -Clicked", 212).show();
                          }
                      });
              }
          });
  ```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this is the duplica tion of this Question

[Google Maps Android API v2 - Interactive InfoWindow (like in original android google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps)

Answer is also specified over there. 
I had also used this answer and it worked for me very well.