# Show InfoWindow only on selected markers, not on all markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am implementing Google maps V2 in my application where am showing three different types of markers, like:

[image]

Now I want to show infowindow only on click of one type of marker, not all markers.

e.g. when user clicks on green marker, it will show info window and when user clicks on blue marker, it will not show info window.

Comment: if you click single balloon you need to popup all balloon show/hide info?

Comment: nono, I just to attach pop up window with only green color markers, on click of other marker, it should not display any info window

Comment: this may helps  you to handle Marker click check [Here ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps