# Android Google Map V2 InfoWindow

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am a beginner in android. I have implemented Google Map v2, but i Want a custom info Window with three button, I went through Documentation, but the default infowindow is single clickable and it cannot have buttons, any way or idea i can do this. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is possible.

You can see the recipe in this answer:[Google Maps Android API v2 - Interactive InfoWindow (like in original android google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps/15040761#15040761)

And a working implementation on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.circlegate.tt.transit.android)

And also here a small [tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html)

Comment: @VishnuPrabhu this is the best achievement ever becoz `Custom Info Window` only provide single click but you can achieve particular button click by using the above post solution

Comment: @MD the Custom window also allowed to achieve particular button click see my answer

Comment: @Jagan you are right but when i click in any button then it's triggered info window click.it's not triggered particular `Button onClick()`. I have tried this so that i told u.

Comment: @MD but we are using LayoutInflater for infowindow that contain button so it triggered both

Answer (score 0):

U need to create a custom window like this

```
class BalloonAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private Button Button1, Button2, Button3;


    public BalloonAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        User_ID = marker.getTitle();


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_ballon, null);

        if(User_ID.equals("Your location")){

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            textViewTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_name);
            textViewTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());

        }else{

        if (marker != null) {

            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_image);

            Button1= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_name);
            Button2 = (Button ) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_age);
            Button3 = (Button ) v.findViewById(R.id.balloon_id);

            Button1.setText(marker.getTitle());
            Button2.setText(marker.getSnippet());
            Button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(ImageLoad, image);
Button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //do wat do u want with this button
        }
    });

Button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //do wat do u want with this button
            }
        });
Button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //do wat do u want with this button
            }
        });

        }
        }
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return (null);
    }

}
```

and You can call the function like this

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(
                                    new LatLng(
                                            Double.parseDouble(Latitude),
                                            Double.parseDouble(Longitude)))
                            .title(User_ID + "\n" + "Name: " + CustomerName
                                    + "\n"+"Gender: " + Gender)
                            .snippet(PhoneNum+"\n"+ImageStatus+"*"+ImageLoad)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.maponinemarker)));
                    map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new BalloonAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
```

this is how u call the infowindo  `map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new BalloonAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));`

Comment: In the above code, where have you set the click listeners for the button @Jagan