# Android: Button click event in custom tooltip Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, tooltip, onclicklistener, layout-inflater

I am trying to make a custom tooltip for my marker on my Google maps on the Android platform.

I tried some stuff and this is what I have for now.

Inflater class:

```
private class InfoHandler implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter, View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tooltip_brewer, null);

        TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_snippet);
        Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_button);
        tvLat.setText("TestTooltip");
        tvLng.setText("TestTooltip 1");
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,  "Test 01");
    }
}
```

Connection to the marker:

```
public void setInfoWindow(LayoutInflater inflater) {
        this.layoutInflater = inflater;
        map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoHandler());
    }
```

Tooltip XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_snippet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="snippet" />

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now everything works accept **I cannot get the click event working on the button in the tooltip**. Does somebody have a solution for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps api v2 custom infowindow like in original android google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because it is not a live view so you cannot do what you want.

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
>   rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is
>   returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
>   be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
>   later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow().
>   Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
>   typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
>   can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
>   described in the section below.

look at the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows