# How to get the screen coordinates of a map's InfoWindow view

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout

I have an InfoWindow in a GoogleMap with buttons in it and am trying a variant of chose007's hack to get those to work (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761)).

My approach relies on getting the screen coordinates of the button inside InfoWindow and operating on it in a `onDispatchTouchEvent` function.

However, all attempts to get the screen coordinates fail. I'm calling it inside `onDispatchTouchEvent` (i.e. long after it has been created), but I get 0,0 for both the button and the view.

I assume this is because InfoWindow's are somehow special cases and not actual UI elements? (IIRC the entire view is basically just a bitmap that's being blitted on top of the map?) Is there any way to get the coordinates? I should mention that I'm trying to avoid anything that involves magic numbers, like chose007's solution in the link.

Here's a simplified illustration of what I'm doing:

```
public boolean onDispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    mTestButton.getLocationOnScreen(location);  // Returns 0,0
    mTestView.getLocationOnScreen(location);    // Returns 0,0

    return false;
}

public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mTestView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.info_window, null);
    mTestButton = ((Button) mTestView.findViewById(R.id.test_button));
}
```

Comment: You are correct in your assumption that the info windows are just drawn snapshots and not part of the `View` hierarchy. The only way to get their positioning is via the "magic numbers" in chose007's answer, which calculates it from the `Marker`'s position and the info window's dimensions, assuming default anchoring and rotation. I have also derived a more generic [implementation](https://gist.github.com/corsair992/8313269) that allows for custom anchoring and rotation and makes the info window live without needing to hack it via touch listeners, which I discussed in the comments on the answer.

Comment: Try displaying your own `PopupWindow` anchored to marker coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

So you've hit a dead end on the infowindow because that's not what you should be using to make really custom infowindows that have buttons and such.  Not this Yankee engineer wouldn't do it that way.

*If you want something custom to show up when the user clicks the marker then capture the marker click show your view at the marker coordinates center the map to the marker coordinates and return `true` from the* `onMarkerClick`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#marker_click_events

```
public boolean onMarkerClick (Marker marker)
```

Called when a marker has been clicked or tapped.
Parameters
marker  The marker that was clicked.
Returns

true if the listener has consumed the event (i.e., the default behavior should not occur), false otherwise (i.e., the default behavior should occur). The default behavior is for the camera to move to the map and an info window to appear.

So how do I put something over the map that takes the shape of a infowindow well I'd need a image or some fancy line art that's not something I have readily available in the source I've worked to cut and paste here.

So how do I put a button over the map.  Well that I can do but for this example the buttons are in static locations.  The Pseudo infowindow you'll have to move the button or image whatever to the coordinates of the marker and maybe center the map on the marker coordinates.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSpeed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="55sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvSpeedUnits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="21sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnFollow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="34dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mapbutton"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:text="@string/btnFollowText"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSatLock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="sat lock"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="21sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGPS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/mapbutton"
        android:paddingLeft="14dp"
        android:paddingRight="14dp"
        android:text="Enable GPS"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Personally I whould simply show a deluxe transparent overlay on the entire screen when the infowindow is clicked.  I mean the user has to click something either way you go.

Good Luck
Signed
One Click ahead of the infoWindow listener.