# InfoWindow issue in Google Map v2 Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, infowindow

I am working with new `Google map V2` in project I have added the `infowindow` on marker click and in my infowindow have two button.

**Issue:** When I click on button1 I want button1 should disable and button2 enable vice versa.
Previously there is `map.invalidate()` with this we can refresh map but how can achieve this in map V2.

I refereed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go) for infoWindow.

Comment: Post your code what you tried till now?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/ it may helps you

Comment: Kindly refer the link I used the same code. I just want to refesh the map so that UI will refresh and update the infoWindow

Comment: @Ramki Anba -There is no method for refreshing the map  :(

Comment: You have two markers, when you click the marker you just get the location of the marker and set a flag for disable.

Comment: Actually button enable disable functionality is working fine but UI of button is not refreshing in infowindow when I click on some other marker at that time infowindow recreate and shows updated UI but I want Ui update instantly when click on buttons.

Comment: What kind of update you want to do?

Comment: I have two buttons on infoWindow of marker I want to invalidate my infoWindow so that if I click on btn1 the btn1 should show disable and btn2 enable and when i click on btn2 the btn2 should show disable and btn1 will show enable.

Answer (score 0):

way around I used show hide of infoWindow on button clicks - marker.showInfoWindow(); marker.hideInfoWindow(); it helps me :)