# Unable to get click event on custominfo window of marker on googlemap V2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am displaying custom infoWindow on marker  by this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761).
Now I am able to show custom infoWindow like
[image]

But problem is that I am unable to get right click event on each button.
e.g. when I click on button1 , it calls touchlistener of button2 and so on.
My code is:

```
this.button1Listener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(
            button1, getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_plusone_medium_off_client),
            getResources().getDrawable(
                    R.drawable.ic_plusone_tall_off_client)) {
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
            // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the
            // button

            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Button1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    };

this.button2Listener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(
                button2, getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ic_plusone_medium_off_client),
                getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ic_plusone_tall_off_client)) {
            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
                // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the
                // button

            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Button2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    };

this.button3Listener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(
                button3, getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ic_plusone_medium_off_client),
                getResources().getDrawable(
                        R.drawable.ic_plusone_tall_off_client)) {
            @Override
            protected void onClickConfirmed(View v, Marker marker) {
                // Here we can perform some action triggered after clicking the
                // button

            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "Button3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    }; and so on.......




this.button1.setOnTouchListener(button1Listener);
        this.button2.setOnTouchListener(button2Listener);
        this.button3.setOnTouchListener(button3Listener);
        .......
        // googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(null);
        googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            button1Listener.setMarker(marker);
            button2Listener.setMarker(marker);
            button3Listener.setMarker(marker);
            ......

            // We must call this to set the current marker and infoWindow
            // references
            // to the MapWrapperLayout
            mapWrapperLayout.setMarkerWithInfoWindow(marker, infoWindow);
            return infoWindow;

        }

    });
```

Please advise me, what I am doing wrong?
Sometimes code works perfectly but most of the time it doesnt work.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved this issue of mismatching click events of buttons.
The problem is here.

```
// MapWrapperLayout initialization
    // 39 - default marker height
    // 20 - offset between the default InfoWindow bottom edge and it's content bottom edge 
    mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));
```

So I just changed:

```
 mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 39 + 20));
```

to

```
mapWrapperLayout.init(map, getPixelsFromDp(this, 0));
```

So there will not be any offset between infowindow bottom edge and it's content.

I hope this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

InfoWindow in Google map V2 is an **Image**, the library rendered all of them as an image. Read the "Note" in "Custom info windows" in [maps Android API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows).

So all buttons which you add to will not work.

If you really want to do so, you have to do some code. I found one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761)

Comment: I am using the same code but unfortunately not working to me as per requirement.