# Custom info window for google maps android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-button, infowindow

I want to have a **`custom info window`** appear on `marker` click.

I want it to be something like this:

```
ImageView

TextView

TextView

TextView

Button  Button
```

I saw other's post question on this, but it's still confusing.

Comment: well for one InfoWindows are not live views so you cannot put a button in the InfoWindow and expect to listen for click events

Comment: is there anyway that i can have it so that a click on marker will allow me click on buttons if not through an info window

Comment: open a dialog on the marker click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About ImageView and TextView, try this:

set an infowindow layout: **infowindowlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your **MapActivity** (this is an example for one marker, but you can use this also for others markers):

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity  {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private Marker Somewhere;
private int markerclicked;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
...
...
final LatLng somewhere = new LatLng(..., ...);

Somewhere=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(somewhere)
.title("YOUR TITLE")
.snippet("INFO")
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));

...
...
...

mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

            // Getting view from the layout file infowindowlayout.xml
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindowlayout, null);

            LatLng latLng = arg0.getPosition();

            ImageView im = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            String title=arg0.getTitle();
            String informations=arg0.getSnippet();

            tv1.setText(title);
            tv2.setText(informations);

            if(onMarkerClick(arg0)==true && markerclicked==1){
               im.setImageResource(R.drawable.yourdrawable);
              }


            return v;

        }
    });
}

public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

if (marker.equals(Somewhere)) 
  {
      markerclicked=1;
      return true;
  }
return false; 
}
```

About Buttons, ImageButtons, etc. there is no way. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker) says:

> As mentioned in the previous section on info windows, an info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.

Anyway, it seems there is a solution, see [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761). I don't know if it is applicable with my code, but it seems work with buttons and imagebuttons.

Comment: this works for the most part, but the image is not showing up

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information about the pre-rendered scene... I was trying to get some buttons in there running but it seems that Google didn't seem to change anything about that in the last 6 years since you answered this question.