# How to get multiple data from ArrayList and display it in snippet google map android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am doing a google map project where I have to fetch the data (title and snippet description) from Array List (which is retrieved from server) and display it in title and snippet dynamically. Since the description in the snippet is lengthy, the whole description is not displayed. The following is my code.

I am able to get a title and a snippet when I tap the marker. What I need is, the snippet should show the lengthy description which comes from server. At present what happens is, there is one title line and one snippet line. The description is shown half in the snippet. If I am not clear please let me know. Need to solve this.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class GoogleActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private static final long MIN_TIME = 700;
    private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 800;

    private Location mLocation;

    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    LatLng myPosition;

    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://webersspot.accountsupport.com/gmaptrial/onedb/phpsqlajax_genxml.php";
    // XML node keys

    static final String KEY_PID = "pro"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";
    static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "Description";
    static final String KEY_LAT = "Latitude";
    static final String KEY_LONG = "Longitude";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> storeMapData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //open the map
        openTheMap();


        /*

     // Get Location Manager and check for GPS & Network location services
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) ||
              !lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
          // Build the alert dialog
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
          builder.setTitle("Location Services Not Active");
          builder.setMessage("Please enable Location Services and GPS");
          builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            // Show location settings when the user acknowledges the alert dialog
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
          });
          Dialog alertDialog = builder.create();
          alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
          alertDialog.show();
        }
         */


        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this); //You can also use LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER and LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER        


        new LongOperation().execute("");
        new MapOperation().execute(googleMap);


    }



    /* open the map */
    private void openTheMap() {
        try {
            if(googleMap == null) {

                SupportMapFragment mapFragment =
                        (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

                googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
                googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);  // Hybrid for satellite with place name
                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);  // enable user location button.
                googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(null) ;
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                googleMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
                googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true); // enable road 
                zoomMap();
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /* zoom current location */
    private void zoomMap() {
        int zoomScale = 12;
        double currentLat = mLocation.getLatitude();
        double currentLon = mLocation.getLongitude();
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLat, currentLon), zoomScale));



    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> prepareData(){

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        //List<HashMap<String, String>>  menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XmlParser parser = new XmlParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_PID);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

            System.out.println("OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO  ::: "+e.getAttribute(KEY_NAME));
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

            map.put(KEY_NAME, e.getAttribute(KEY_NAME).toString());
            map.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION ,e.getAttribute(KEY_DESCRIPTION).toString());
            map.put(KEY_LAT, e.getAttribute(KEY_LAT).toString());
            map.put(KEY_LONG ,e.getAttribute(KEY_LONG).toString());


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
            storeMapData = menuItems;



        }
        return menuItems;

    }

    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {       
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> processData = storeMapData;



        System.out.println( "kjkasdc   "+processData);

        for (int i=0; i< processData.size(); i++){


            final double lat = Double.parseDouble(processData.get(i).get(KEY_LAT));
            System.out.println("MAP LAT :::::::::::::::::::::::::  "+lat);
            final double lon =  Double.parseDouble(processData.get(i).get(KEY_LONG));
            System.out.println("MAP LON :::::::::::::::::::::::::  "+lon);
            final String address = processData.get(i).get(KEY_DESCRIPTION);
            System.out.println("MAP ADDRESS :::::::::::::::::::::::::  "+address);
            final String name = processData.get(i).get(KEY_NAME);
            System.out.println("MAP ADDRESS :::::::::::::::::::::::::  "+name);




            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lon)).title(name).snippet(address).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));



                }
            });

        }
    }



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        /** Inflating the current activity's menu with res/menu/items.xml */
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);     

        mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share).getActionProvider();

        /** Setting a share intent */
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(getDefaultShareIntent());


        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }    

    /** Returns a share intent */
    private Intent getDefaultShareIntent(){     
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");       
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Download");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Download Hill Top Beauty Parlour App - Maroli from Google Play Store:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=beauty.parlour.maroli");        
        return intent;
    }


    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {         
            prepareData();      
            return "Executed";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
            System.out.println("Executed");
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {         
            System.out.println("Execution started");            
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            System.out.println("     -- -- -- "+values);
        }
    }

    private class MapOperation extends AsyncTask<GoogleMap, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(GoogleMap... params) {    
            GoogleMap map = params[0];
            onMapReady(map);    
            return "Executed";
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {               
            System.out.println(result);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {         
            System.out.println("Execution started");            
        }
        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

            System.out.println("     -- -- -- "+values);
        }
    }

    class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

        private final View myContentsView;

        MyInfoWindowAdapter(){
            myContentsView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            TextView tvTitle = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.title));
            tvTitle.setText(marker.getTitle());


            TextView tvaddress = ((TextView)myContentsView.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
            tvaddress.setText(marker.getTitle());




            return myContentsView;
        }



        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

At present I am able to get a title and a snippet when I tap the marker. What I need is, the snippet should show the lengthy description which comes from server. At present what happens is, there is one title line and one snippet line. The description is shown half in the snippet. If I am not clear please let me know. Need to solve this.

Comment: What is your question?  Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Yash can you show your custom infowindow layout?

Comment: no. That's the issue

Comment: is there any ready code for infowindow? where I can write description 4-5 lines?

Comment: @Yash check my updated answer. I cited a similar question to guide you on custom info window

Comment: You're probably hitting the character limit for snippet, or there is a special character that is truncating the String. Using a custom InfoWindow to split up the info might help.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30069852/4409409

Answer (score 0):

You would need to check the layout of your custom info window and make sure that the Textview for description accepts more than 1 line. Setting the  lines or maxLines property in the layout or in the code will help you achieve this. Make sure also that the layout_height and layout_width is properly set.

You may refer to this question -> [Custom info window for google maps android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618970/custom-info-window-for-google-maps-android) as a guide on how to create a custom info window

Comment: have you checked the link?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090148/custom-info-window-adapter-with-custom-data-in-map-v2        I want something like this

Comment: @Yash yes i know. your code isn't right that's why i pointed you on how to create a custom info window and gave you some tips on how to fulfill the requirement.