# How to add image to information windows in Google Maps Api v3 android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wanna know how to add an image inside of the information box event from google maps markers.

Hello, guys! I need some help about how to add an image inside of the information box event that shows up when you click in the marker.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
    //Parking 1 Central Park Rua Arlindo Colaço - SM 216
     LatLng est1 = new LatLng(-23.492668, -46.4419270);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(est1).title("Central Park").snippet("Rua Arlindo Colaço, 216"));
```

This Peace of code is adding one marker into the google maps in my android Project and it shows that information "Central Park" as a title and "Rua Arlingo Colaço, 216" as a line of text.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is customize the info window.Please have a look at this :
[Custom info window for google maps android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618970/custom-info-window-for-google-maps-android)