# Android Maps: Different info windows for different markers

Tags: android, google-maps

I am following this SO post Accepted answer **( [Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761) )** for showing info windows on `Map`. I have achieved that to show info window for a `marker`, but now I want to show different info windows for different markers. So how can I achieve this? Any help will be highly appreciated and thanks in advance.