# Google maps v2 android, info window not highlighting in the default highlight color on click?

Tags: android, click, maps, highlight, infowindow

I have problem that infowindow in Google Maps Android is not working as it supposed to. When clicked is supposed to highlight with default blue color but nothing happens with color of infoWindow , onInfoWindowClick is called normally.

Any advice how to solve this problem and force highlighting on infowindow when taped?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working for me too. Looks like we have to go deeper for such functionality :

As we know, InfoWindow is not live View, it is just an image rendered from view using View.draw(Canvas) as mentioned here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows

To enable touch events or custom layout button click events, one has to unlock them, or Override pre-defined methods for InfoWindow. Such a problem is solved here :

[Google Maps Android API v2 - Interactive InfoWindow (like in original android google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761)

Comment: I understand that infoWindow is not a live view , but default behavior worked as it suppose to on previus versions of my AP , I think something changed with google play services. I don't recollect when it has stooped working.

Regards and tnx for your input but unfortunately i doesn't resolve my problem.