# How to make Android interactive InfoWindow over Google Maps API2 Transparent

Tags: android, transparency, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I implemented [perfect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/) of [chose007](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1970966/chose007) to make InfoWindow over Google Maps API2 clickable in my app. The only problem is, that I would like to make InfoWindow transparent (to make it bubble shaped). I can do it with non-interactive InfoWindow using style wrapper:

```java
gMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

           ContextThemeWrapper cw = new ContextThemeWrapper(
                 getApplicationContext(),R.style.TransparentDialog);
              LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) cw
                 .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_bubble,
                 null);
           return layout;
        }
```

The InfoWindow appears as transparent, but it is not possible to set the contents of the window in:

```java
 @Override
         public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
            // Setting up the infoWindow with current's marker info
         TextView bubHd = (TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.bubble_hd);
         bubHd.setText(places.get(placeId).getTitle());
           .
           .
           .
```

And it is not more interactive as the interactivity is also set inside `getInfoContents` and it seems to me, that this method is not called at all if `getInfoWindow` returns non `null` result.

Does anybody know, how to make the interactive InfoWindow over Google Maps transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The InfoWindow appears as transparent, but it is not possible to set the contents of the window in `getInfoContents()`

Correct. If `getInfoWindow()` returns a non-`null` value, you are supposed to return the *complete* info window with the *complete* contents, and `getInfoContents()` will not be called. Move your `getInfoContents()` method body statements into `getInfoWindow()`.