# Put layout above google Map marker Android

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I have a custom "InfoWindow" for a marker, which has buttons, but for default user can't click over the buttons or slide on lists of that layout because that info window is like an image.

Note: the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2183804 doesn't apply to my problem because different markers has different info Windows (I already tried modifying that answer without success).

So, to solve my problem, I though on putting a layout above the marker when the user clicks over the marker. How can I achieve to put the layout above the marker?

[image: Example]

In this example, I have a list with clickable items in the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution can be find on this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31995000/3957303

The basic idea is to use a `PopupWindow` to show the layout on the screen, and then play with its location to potition it over the marker with the `updatePopup` method described in the answer. And every time the camera changes (listening to the `CameraChangeListener`), you call the `updatePopup` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this by adding a custom info window adapter. And then set it to my map . And in `getInfoWindow()` of adapter ,you can write all the click listeners to your views.Here is the code .

```
    private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {


        private View view;

        public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {

            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            if (marker != null
                    && marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                marker.hideInfoWindow();
                marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {

            final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));

            final String title = marker.getTitle();
            final TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
            if (title != null) {
                titleUi.setText(title);
            } else {
                titleUi.setText("");
            }


            return view;
        }

    }
```

And set it to map by this

```
 private GoogleMap mMap;
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());
```

Hope it helps. Happy coding...

Comment: please, improve that code. Why commented code? url, image and snipped is not used. getLayoutInflater and getApplicationContext cannot be resolved. Can't find FontHelper nor Utility

Comment: Where do I find FontHelper and Utility classes?

Comment: I leave view name it that just to hep you understand how views works in there.

Comment: Ok. In your code dont have the OnClick that I am looking for. Even though I put it in my code, the button "onClick" neither works...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86880/discussion-between-diie-barcia-and-nouman-ghaffar).

Comment: In summary, this solution does not solve this question problem.