# Custom info window with buttons

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I create a custom info window with multiple buttons to click.
I want to open a circular menu(custom info window) around the clicked marker and then track the menu items click.

When I tried searching for it, the only solution I found is:
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons
Which is deprecated

And the Map Utils library doesn't seem to have anything related to this(Or at least I couldn't find it in the description)
https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Any helpful pointer is much appreciated.

Comment: are you looking for customize info window ??

Comment: This link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go

Comment: @Sree Yes, which can be any view(with buttons labels etc..)

Comment: @MohitSuthar Thanks. I actually looked at that solution before posting the question. That solution looks like an overkill. I was looking for something which is simple like the iOS map annotations. Also that solution is 3 years old.

Comment: @Housefly I know bt i also try to implement this kind of thing bt no other solutions thats why i also use this solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761