# How to show and image in the google maps pin info in android?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add an image from my backend to a certain pin, currently I can add the title and the snippet but how do i add and image to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create Custom Info window for that. For Official documentation, you can refer this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows

Also you can find a sample tutorial here http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html

Also one more thing, you may not be able to distinguish between click events on various components of the layout as mentioned in the documentation.

> As mentioned in the previous section on info windows, an info window
>   is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the
>   map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded
>   and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of
>   the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such
>   as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info
>   window.

But you can follow this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761) for making them work.

Comment: Thanks! that works :D