# Add marquee textview to google infowindow in android?

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

I have a Textview in customized google info window.

Added marquee to textview

```
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:text="Single-line text view that scrolls automatically if the text is too long to fit in the widget"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

also added setSelected to scroll.

```
 View v = LayoutInflater.from( getActivity() ).inflate( R.layout.view_info_window, null );
TextView scroll = (TextView) v.findViewById( R.id.scroll );
            scroll.setSelected(true);
```

But the text is not scrolling in info window. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

you have to add selected true programatically .

```
textview.SetSelected(true)
```

*update*

*google info window in not live view so you are not able to achieve what you are trying to achive.*

Comment: I have added that part also, but some how its not working in infowindow..marquee is working for a textview in normal layout

Comment: oh google info window in not live view so you are not able to achieve what you are trying to achive. @user9213

Comment: Is there any other way i can do it?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761 . kind of hard though. @user9213