# Andorid- how to get position of google map info window so set something else on this position?

Tags: android, google-maps, position, infowindow

I want to get the position of a google maps info window as to be Seen in the following image so I can set floating button on that position for clicking to perform some task.

[image]

I want to set floating button position after showing popup info in particular position.

Please don't refer [this answer i'll already apply this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761) but sometimes not perform right way.

Answer (score 0):

Upon checking the [MarkerOptions](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions#developer-guide), there is no class that can get the location of the infowindow. The closest we can get is getInfoWindowAnchorU and getInfoWindowAnchorV.

**`getInfoWindowAnchorU ()`**

> Horizontal distance, normalized to [0, 1], of the info window anchor from the left edge.

**`getInfoWindowAnchorV ()`**

> Vertical distance, normalized to [0, 1], of the info window anchor from the top edge.

Also, it was advised in this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows):

> You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.

Hope it helps!