# Google maps v2 custom Infowindow with two buttons

Tags: android, maps, android-7.0-nougat

I used [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/8112541) 
to create a custom `InfoWindow` with 2 **`buttons`** . It works OK on every mobile except the ones with **`Android 7`**.