# Can we add Actions inside Marker Snippet?

Tags: android, google-maps

Can we add `Actions` inside `Marker Snippet` like Delete marker `button`, navigate `button` etc., We can remove marker by clicking the `marker`. But, I don't want that because i want to show `snippet` when i click the `marker`. so, Definetly i need to actions to `snippet` or `infoWindow`. I'm surprised that i didn't find any useful solution to me.
Here is the code how to remove the marker when onClick marker

```
Marker locationMarker = mMap.addMarker(
                new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(userName)
                        .snippet(getLocation(latLng)));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14.0f));
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                            marker.remove();
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
```

If any guide me how can i do that.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question?

Comment: see question now i that i need snippet compulsory but i need the functionality delete particular marker so i 'm thinking of adding action inside snippet how can i do that

Comment: is there any way to delete particular marker

Comment: This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761

Comment: can we add buttons inside the Info window?

Comment: Yes you can add

Comment: i don't want to implement functionality on info window i want a button inside it and when i click that button only it should delete otherwise it should not delete i mean when i touch remaining part of info window it should not delete. is it provide that functionality

Comment: can we help with some code if so

Comment: You can add just a button also

Comment: can you provide some code

Comment: with example please

Comment: If you add some code then I can modify and show you

Comment: Or else you can show a simple dialog before deleting the marker

Comment: can i add in answer section

Comment: Check this https://github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid

Comment: ya i'm seeing that

Comment: your most welcome :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160080/discussion-between-lokesh-kanumoori-and-anonymous).

Comment: The git hub library should definitely help you