# Custom info window of google map with item click with kotlin

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I tried to get click of items from info window of google maps .
I took reference from here : [Google Maps Android API v2 - Interactive InfoWindow (like in original android google maps)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761)

But not able to work properly in kotlin .

Comment: You should post the code your tried at least. Can u specify your question? Do you need to open a custom info window on google maps marker click?

Comment: I got success to open custom view in info window of google map .
But not able to get clicks of items which was I added in custom view like radio buttons, edit text and buttons.

Comment: Hello @BetaRunner here is my code:  https://github.com/ParthThakar2012/GoogleMapKotlin.git
IN this demo it works for now but I want to open and set dynamically added markers in map. 
can you please looking more into it if you can.