# How can I add lines and buttons to a marker?

Tags: java, android, marker, mapactivity

I am trying to display some information when the user clicks on a marker using the snippet of `Marker` class. As far as I know, the problem is that it can be only 1 line long, so I can't add a new line to make the information clearer. Is there any way to display more than one single line? 
I'm using default `MapActivity` and googleMap API V2 
Thank you in advance for your patience and consideration.

Comment: You can create custom info window and make like this mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(customInfoWindow);

Comment: @VadimEksler could you please be more precise? What do you mean by "custom info window"? Could you please add some code?

Comment: look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom info window. Take a look this dock https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#custom_info_windows

Adapter example:

```
public class CustomInfoWindow implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
    Context context; 
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public CustomInfoWindow(Context context) {
           this.context = context;
    }
    @Override    
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {        
        return null;    
    }
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)
context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  

   // R.layout.custom_info_window is a layout
   // res/layout folder. You can provide your own
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);   

    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_title);     
  TextView subtitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.info_window_subtitle);
    title.setText(marker.getTitle());
    subtitle.setText(marker.getSnippet());
    return v;
    }
}
```

And for use it you need to make:
`map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindow(context));`

Comment: Can I add buttons in a custom info window too?

Comment: for two buttons you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761#15040761

Comment: ok thank you very much!