# Inflate a custom View inside google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmsgroundoverlay

How to inflate a custom view inside a google map fragment?

To add images/points on map we can use Markers or GroundOverlay, but if we need a custom view (for example, a list or an image with buttons), both classes receive a BitmapDescriptor on their attributes `.icon` and `.image`, respectively, which turns a given layout into a plain image, losing its versatility, for example unable to add onClickListeners on buttons.

So is there a way to add a custom view inside google map fragment without it being transformed into an image?

Comment: what exactly you want to accomplish by adding this custom view ?

Comment: @VivekMishra for now, add a layout with texts and interactions, initially onClicks

Comment: then, instead of adding it to google map can't you just overlay a view over the map using frame layout ?

Comment: well, lets add that i want to add this view directly into a position - if i attach it over the map than it would be fixed and i would have to disable map interactions (such as dragging etc)

Comment: can a custom infowindow for a marker help you ?

Comment: that's an approach i'm open to discuss

Comment: This link might help you https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows

Comment: @VivekMishra This part of documentation was important "Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view...". There is no way to add multiple clicks on different items on a Marker/Ground/InfoWindow... that was the best answer for my question, therefore ill close this, ty for linking it

Comment: so what you want to accomplish can't be done ?

Comment: I did found one answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-android-api-v2-interactive-infowindow-like-in-original-android-go/15040761 and one library https://github.com/Appolica/InteractiveInfoWindowAndroid that could lead into an answer. Yet one seems overcomplicated (not their fault) and other makes you dependent on a 3rd party. What i want is something in the middle, where you can create it and don't need to create so many behaviours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation clearly states that views will be rendered into images which annul any changes previously given to the view. Therefore there is no way to create a custom view with different behaviours inside google map.

> Note: The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is
> rendered as an image (using View.draw(Canvas)) at the time it is
> returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not
> be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window
> later (for example, after an image has loaded), call showInfoWindow().
> Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity
> typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you
> can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as
> described in the section below.

From documentation: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows)