# Android google map api 2 - click on map pin to launch external intent for driving direction

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I would like to add a button to the map pin's snippet to launch an external intent for driving direction to the pin.

I am thinking I can implement something that listens to long click the snippet box, brings up a pop-up to see if user would like to see driving direction and then launches the external activity.

Not sure there is an easy way to do it or the best UX design. Open up to suggestions!

This is my current setup map function:

```
private void maybeSetUpMapPin() {
  mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
  CameraUpdate cameraUpdate;

  for (Location location : mLocations) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
      .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
      .title(location.getName())
      .snippet(location.getDescription());
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
  }
  CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory
      .newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(DEFAULT_LATITUDE, DEFAULT_LONGITUDE), 10.0f);
  mMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Check out 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14123243/google-maps-api-v2-custom-infowindow-like-in-original-android-google-maps?lq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810002/adding-buttons-to-map-infowindow-android

Comment: @Erzer Thanks for the suggestion :) Seems like a great idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this by using `Custom Marker Window` implementation in `Google Map V2 API`.

An **info window** allows you to display information to the user when they tap on a marker. Only one info window is displayed at a time. If a user clicks on another marker, the current info window will be hidden and the new info window will be displayed.

An info window is drawn oriented against the device's screen, centered above its associated marker. The default info window contains the title in bold, with the (optional) snippet text below the title

Here i saw some link given below

- [custom info window adapter with custom data in map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090148/custom-info-window-adapter-with-custom-data-in-map-v2)
- [Android Google maps APIv2 InfoWindow and Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334390/android-google-maps-apiv2-infowindow-and-markers)
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows

What i achieved by using this?

[image]

and another is

[image]

hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :) Looks good! Gonna do some read up on what needs to be done now.

Comment: @JoanneChow thnx. If you need any help just Ping me!